# Proving that ring is local iff set of non-units is an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know that there is already a duplicate of this issue; however, I don't understand the proof yet and therefore open a new question ... I hope that this is ok.

For the proof I used this link: 
https://yutsumura.com/a-ring-is-local-if-and-only-if-the-set-of-non-units-is-an-ideal/

In the following, I will use the notation of the website.

(i) Let $a, b\in I$. We then show (by exploiting that $M$ is a maximal ideal) that $a, b \in M$ as well. Then, obviously, $a-b\in M$ as well, since $M$ is an ideal. But why does $a-b \in I$ hold? "As $M$ is a proper ideal, $a-b$ is a non-unit [...]." > I don't understand this yet. Similarly for $ra\in I$: I understand why $ra\in M$ holds, but not $ra\in I$.

(ii) $\Leftarrow$ $M$ is a proper ideal, since $1\in R$ is a unit. But why is every element of $M$ a non-unit, how exactly does it relate to $M$ being a proper ideal?

Kind regards, 
MathIsFun

Comment: In ii), every element of $R\setminus M$ is a unit, not every element of $M$.  The thing you are reading says _every element of $M$ is a **non-unit**_

Comment: If $R-R^\times$ is an ideal then it is the largest proper ideal, and every ideal is contained it, thus it is the only maximal ideal. If there is only one maximal ideal $m$ then $a$ not a unit implies $(a)$ is a proper ideal thus contained in some maximal ideal which has to be $m$, and $u$ a unit implies $u\not \in m$ thus $m = R-R^\times$ (also note $m$ can be the $0$ ideal in which case $R$ is a field).

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to MSE! I think you have some things mixed up. I will use your notation.

(i) I assume you understand in both instances that the elements are in the maximal ideal $M$. Elements in maximal ideals are always non-units (because otherwise $M = R$). So we use $M \subseteq I$ to conclude that the elements are in $I$.

(ii) What you said here doesn't make much sense to me. Maximal ideals are by definition always proper. As above, proper ideals have only non-units, so this means $M \subseteq I$ for any maximal ideal $M$. But maximality of $M$ gives $M = I$. Thus, $I$ is the unique maximal ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers and comments so far. In tbe meantime, I found the following post: [If an ideal contains the unit then it is the whole ring](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/552173/if-an-ideal-contains-the-unit-then-it-is-the-whole-ring)

This then answers my questions.

PS: I realized one problem though: When proving $\Leftarrow$, I don't think we can simply assume that there exists an arbitrary maximal ideal, but its existence must be proven!