# Proving that factor ring R/I is local if R is local

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Here I asked how to prove that a ring is local iff the set of non-units is an ideal: [Proving that ring is local iff set of non-units is an ideal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3461443/proving-that-ring-is-local-iff-set-of-non-units-is-an-ideal)

Now we are supposed to show in our homework that if $R$ is local (i.e., it contains exactly one maximal ideal) and $I\subsetneq R$ is an ideal, then $R/I$ is local. I found this previous post: [Quotient ring local if Ring is local](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3063196/quotient-ring-local-if-ring-is-local)

Now, I read through the marked answer and showed that $\pi(M)$ is an ideal (easy exercise). [I use the notation $\pi: R\rightarrow R/I, r\mapsto r+I$ instead of $f$.]

So it remains to be shown that $\pi(M)$ is maximal. I thought of using the fact that $I$ is maximal iff $R/I$ is a field. 
Would I then - in this task - have to show that $(R/I)/I$ is a field in this task, or am I misunderstanding it? However, how could we show that $(R/I)/I$ is a field?

Kind regards,
MathIsFun

Comment: The answer you referred to ([this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3063204/27542)) notes that the lattice isomorphism theorem proves that any ideal of $R/I$ is contained in $\pi(M)$. What more do you need?

Comment: (R/I)/I isn't even defined.  I think what you really mean to write is $(R/I)/(I/I)$, but that is not helpful.

Comment: Alekos Robotis's answer at the question you linked seems to explain everything you are asking about...

Comment: The lattice isomorphism is containment preserving, therefore $I\subseteq K\subseteq M$ implies $\pi(K)\subseteq \pi(M)$ for every ideal $K$. And all the ideals of the quotient arise this way.  There is nothing left to show...

Comment: Yes, I see ... But I am afraid that we haven't covered the "lattice isomorphism theorem" yet. We had that $ker \varphi \cong im \varphi$ and then a commuting diagram, but I looked on Wikipedia (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems) and didn't find your version of the statement ...

Comment: Third and fourth isomorphism theorems [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems#Third_isomorphism_theorem_2). It's a little hard to believe that you're asked to solve this problem if you've never seen the ring isomorphism theorems...