# Why $r \notin R^*$ if it is a prime?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, prime-factorization, maximal-and-prime-ideals

My professor gave us the following definition:

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. $r \in R$ is prime if $r.R$ is a prime ideal. Then he concluded that this definition tells us $r \notin R^*$ but I do not understand why, could anyone explain this to me please?

**Answer(based on comments given below the question):**

A prime ideal is by definition a proper ideal, and if $r$ is a unit then $rR = R.$

The proof can be found in this link [If an ideal contains the unit then it is the whole ring](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/552173/if-an-ideal-contains-the-unit-then-it-is-the-whole-ring) and here it is:

**Proposition.** Let $I$ be a left or right ideal of a ring $R$ with unity.
Then $I = R$ *if and only* if $I$ contains *a unit*.

*Proof:* Let $I$ be a left ideal of $R$. If $I = R$ then $1 \in I$, so $I$ contains a unit.
Conversely, if $u \in I$ is any unit, let $u^{-1}$ be its inverse.
For any $r \in R$, we have $r = r (u^{-1} u) = (r u^{-1}) u \in I$, because $I$ is a left ideal. Thus $I = R$. This logic is easily adapted for right ideals to show the same result. Certainly it then is true for two-sided ideals and ideals of unital commutative rings.

Comment: a prime ideal is by definition a proper ideal, and if $r$ is a unit then $rR=R$

Comment: I am sorry for my stupid question .... but why if $r$ is a unit, then $rR = R$?@AtticusStonestrom

Comment: @Math Also answered on the site https://math.stackexchange.com/q/552173/29335

Comment: @rschwieb thank you so much! that link really solved my problem.

Comment: @Math Would you mind updating your question with a self-solution then? That would be preferable to it living on the way it is now.

Comment: Ok @rschwieb I will.

Comment: @Math ah, the solution you've written is not *quite* right – for an arbitrary unit $u$, there is no guarantee that $ru=r$ for any nonzero $r\in R$. (consider $-1$ in $\mathbb{Z}$, for instance). instead, you want to say that there is an element $v\in R$ such that $uv=vu=1$ (this is the definition of a unit), and then $(rv)u=r(vu)=r\in I$ for any $r\in R$. does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah it makes a lot of sense@AtticusStonestrom I edited my solution. Thank you!